# How to keep nstimer run in background?

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I am using the bellow  code but timer kill in background. but i want to keep running my nstimer in background-

```
          NSTimeInterval time = 5;
          self.locationUpdateTimer =
          [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:time
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateLocation1)
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:NO];
```

Comment: are you trying to update something when your device moves some distance or changes location?

Comment: yes. i am trying to do that when app kept in background for 2 minutes it will call a method and when time is bellow 2 minute it will another method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location events while the app is in the background, [and here is Apple documentation that explains how to do that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10).  And you probably also want to use something called ["the Significant-Change Location Service"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8).

And when the change happens, you'll get a call on your CoreLocation method ["`location manager: didUpdateLocations:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a).  Sample code can be seen in the "Significant-Change Location Service" section.

Doing the above will be a lot easier to do than to try to implement a timer that runs while your application is in the background (and probably fully suspended, as many apps tend to be).

And if you didn't get a location update, that means your phone didn't move. :-)

Comment: can u please tell me is there any other way to count time in background? i am trying to do after 2 minute in background  user will be logout automatically from their account but if time is less than 2 minute in background user will not logout from their account .